# KVM / QEMU / VMM : local host not connected

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed `kvm`. When I try to open virtual machine, I get this error:

```
local host not connected

Unable to connect to libvirt.

Verify that:
 - The 'libvirt-bin' package is installed
 - The 'libvirtd' daemon has been started
 - You are member of the 'libvirtd' group

Unable to connect to libvirt.

Verify that:
 - The 'libvirt-bin' package is installed
 - The 'libvirtd' daemon has been started
 - You are member of the 'libvirtd' group

Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1027, in _open_thread
    self.vmm = self._try_open()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1009, in _try_open
    flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 105, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Permission denied
```

Comment: Have you installed `libvirt-bin`? (check with `apt-cache policy libvirt-bin`)? Are you a member of the `libvirtd` group? (check with `groups`)? You should also follow the steps described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM) to install and use KVM.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1** : Install all packages that are needed.

```
sudo apt-get install qemu virt-manager
```

If they already are installed, you get notified.

**Step 2** : Add yourself to the libvirt(d) group.

```
sudo usermod -G libvirt -a <username>
```

(this is valid for newer KVM / Ubuntu versions)

```
sudo usermod -G libvirtd -a <username>
```

(this is valid for older KVM / Ubuntu versions)

Replace `<username>` with ***your* user name**.

**Step 3** : Reboot your host operating system.

```
sudo reboot
```

Now everything should work as expected.

In case you still get the same error again -

open `virt-manager` with root privileges :

```
sudo apt-get install gksu  

gksudo virt-manager
```

Close `virt-manager` and restart the host.

```
sudo reboot
```

Finally it should work with user privileges !

Comment: `usermod: group 'libvirtd' does not exist` in running step 2 after running step 1. I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://chromeunboxed.com/installing-pop-os-chromebook-virtual-machine-crostini-linux-vm/ and also have "qemu/kvm not connected" on virtual machine manager

Comment: @Justin This thread is about five years old - meanwhile the group has changed because newer versions of KVM have a default group libvirt - so just execute `sudo usermod -G libvirt -a <username>`. I have updated the answer accordingly. :)

Comment: Thank you. I actually got it working another way, but I appreciate the reply and updating the answer : )